# Existe alguma função de Excel que retorne o corpo de outra função?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Exemplo simples do que eu desejo: suponha que na célula A1 eu tenha o valor 2, na célula A2 eu tenha o valor 3 e na célula A3 eu tenha a fórmula =A1+A2.

Se eu colocar na célula A4 a fórmula =A3, ela obviamente me retornará o valor 5 e o que eu gostaria é de uma fórmula que me retornasse a string '=A1+A2'. Existe essa fórmula?

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Pode-se usar a função: `=FÓRMULATEXTO(A3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma Função Definida pelo Usuário (UDF) pode ser criada para versões Excel 2010 ou anteriores:

```
Function MostraFormula(Rng As Range, Optional asR1C1 As Boolean = False) As String
    If asR1C1 Then
        MostraFormula = Rng.FormulaR1C1
    Else
        MostraFormula = Rng.FormulaLocal
    End If
End Function
```

Então inserindo os seguintes dados de exemplo:

```
      A   B        C                 D           
 --- --- --- -------------- -------------------- 
  1   2   3   =SOMA(A1;B1)   =MostraFormula(C1)  
  2                                              
  3
```

O resultado é:

```
      A   B   C        D        
 --- --- --- --- -------------- 
  1   2   3   5   =SOMA(A1,B1)  
  2                             
  3
```

Ou com `=MostraFormula(C1; VERDADEIRO)` o resultado é `=SUM(RC[-2],RC[-1])`

Comment: Daniel, isso seria MACRO? +1

Comment: Isso, é possível somente com VBA (macro). Em que uma função personalizada é criada.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar a `FÓRMULATEXTO()`

Exemplo:

[image: plan]

Sendo:

A1 = `10`

B1 = `20`

C1 = `=A1+B1`

E1 = `=FÓRMULATEXTO(C1)`

---

#### Complementando

Um exemplo simples utilizando a função para montar uma memória de cálculo:

[image: form1]

Se utilizar o recurso de intervalos nomeados, pode deixar o aspecto ainda melhor…

[image: form2]

---

Referência: [Dica de Função – FÓRMULATEXTO](https://usuariosdoexcel.wordpress.com/2016/05/04/dica-de-formula-formulatexto/)

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta, mas essa função FÓRMULATEXTO só existe no Office 2013 e o meu Excel é versão 2010.

Comment: @Marcelo A resposta do danieltakeshi irá funcionar para seu caso. Como minha resposta poderá servir para demais, irei deixá-la. ✌️